# How can I send my Instagram access token from my Express server to React client?

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have 2 different apps running on different ports. 1 is a React client the other is an Express server. The server is very simple, it just receives the code from Instagram and makes a post request to get the access token.

I got the access token but I want to send it back to the client so it can use it. But the client does not make a request to the server.

The flow works like this.

Client -> Press button to authenticate user

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => {
          window.open('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000&response_type=code', '_blank')
        }}>Authenticate</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

And then the server receives the code

```
router
.get("/", (req, res) => {
  if (req.query.code !== 'undefined') {
    axios.post('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', querystring.stringify({
      'client_id': '6',
      'client_secret': 'e',
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8000',
      'code': req.query.code
    }))
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
})
```

My .then response receives the authenticated object but now I'm stuck. How can I use the authenticated object in my client? How do I send it back to the client? Should I be sending it back?

My client is running on port 8080

I would prefer to make all the api calls in my client because that is what I know. I don't know express well enough and would rather just work with what I know which is React / Redux.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is to send the data in your response.

for that you will need to write

```
res.send(response.data);
```

Comment: But my client doesn't send a request. It opens a new tab with the Instagram login request and no call is made from the client. I would be res.send()ing to instagram?